# alert message on click input radio

Tags: angularjs, input, onclick, radio-button

I have 0% knowledges in web programming in general, but I need to solve this particular problem.

Why the onclick event doesnt work in this code (angular template dashboard) ? No alert messages appears

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8a2H.png)

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqdG7.png)

Comment: why on earth are you setting a script tag in angular? Oh wait... this is angularjs. Please add correct tags in future. This time I fixed it for you.

Comment: From your image I can see that you are using the ng-controller directive, is there a reason you aren't using ng-click and a function that is a part of your controller?

Comment: ng-click doesnt work

Comment: <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" ng-click="alert()"> Day
 $scope.alert=function () {
    alert('hi');
  }; DOESNT WORKS

Answer (score -1):

In your html
`<input type="radio" name="options" (click)="myFunction()">`

In your ts file

`myFunction(){
    alert('click')
 }`

In angular onclick is (click)

Comment: yes, but I only have main.html y main.js . I dont have ts file. I need to change the data of the chart clicking in day, month, year. This is the controller trafficDemoCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
function trafficDemoCtrl($scope){ inside main.js

Comment: Are you sure your project is on Angular ? What version of angular you are using ?

Comment: I have only two days editing angular template dashboard D: This is the important code https://i.imgur.com/TSZqgyL.png
I am editing Alba AngularJS Admin Template  https://coreui.io/angularjs/

Comment: My solution is for Angular 2+. Someone with experience in angularjs will help you.